# How do I select data from a XML column on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

How do I select data from a XML column in a SQL Server table in SQL Server Management Studio?

I would like to get this result:

```
orderDdate  createdBby  orderNo currency    taxation    inv customer    mail
2019-09-05  storefront  000001  USD gross   0099999 Jonh Smith  JonhSmith@gmail.com

<orders xmlns="www address">
<order>
    <order-date>2019-09-05</order-date>
    <created-by>storefront</created-by>
    <original-order-no>000001</original-order-no>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <taxation>gross</taxation>
    <invoice-no>0099999</invoice-no>
    <customer>
        <customer-name>Jonh Smith</customer-name>
        <customer-email>JonhSmith@gmail.com</customer-email>
    </customer>
    <notes>
        <note>
            <created-by>system</created-by>
            <creation-date>2019-09-06T07:05:03.000Z</creation-date>
            <subject>Fulfilment Status</subject>
            <text>The order fulfilment status was changed from '01' to '02'.</text>
        </note>
        <note>
            <created-by>system</created-by>
            <creation-date>2019-09-06T07:05:03.000Z</creation-date>
            <subject>Fulfilment Status</subject>
            <text>The order fulfilment status was changed from '02' to '03'.</text>
        </note>
        <note>
            <created-by>system</created-by>
            <creation-date>2019-09-06T07:05:03.000Z</creation-date>
            <subject>Fulfilment Status</subject>
            <text>The order fulfilment status was changed from '03' to '03'.</text>
        </note>
    </notes>

<product-lineitems>
    <product-lineitem>
        <product-id>0001</product-id>
        <quantity unit="BOX">1.0</quantity>
        <tax-rate>0.23</tax-rate>
    </product-lineitem>
    <product-lineitem>
        <product-id>0002</product-id>
        <quantity unit="PCS">1.0</quantity>
        <tax-rate>0.23</tax-rate>
    </product-lineitem>
</product-lineitems>
</order>
```

I have the last problem (i hope) ;)

How to return data from product-lineitems. I mean: Quantity, Quantity-unit

Im trying like that: But it's return duplicate rows :(

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'www address')
SELECT 
    o.value(N'(current-order-no/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS OrderNo
    ,n.value(N'(quantity/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS Qty
    ,u.value(N'@unit',N'varchar(10)') AS Unit
FROM 
    dbSupply.dbo.MyXmlTable t
CROSS APPLY 
    t.XMLData.nodes(N'/orders/order') A(o)
OUTER APPLY 
    A.o.nodes(N'product-lineitems/product-lineitem') B(n)
OUTER APPLY 
    A.o.nodes(N'product-lineitems/product-lineitem/quantity') C(u)
```

'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details'
'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details'
'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details'

Comment: Always best to include Desired Results?  It would eliminate assumptions, for example are you looking for columns or rows?

Comment: *"How do I select data from xml file on sql server management studio?"* SSMS is simply an application used to perform operations against a SQL Server instance (normally using SQL). You don't use SSMS to read the file (row I assume) you use SQL Server to do so. SSMS on it's own, with no SQL Server instance to connect to, could do nothing to "select" data from an XML file. In this case, you would need to write a SQL Statement that uses [XQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Im looking rows

Comment: *"Im looking rows"* But `order-date` is clearly a `date` and `created-by` a `varchar`. You can't have different data types in the same column. Can you show us (in your question) what you expect your final result set to look like please? Your own attempt(s) would be really helpful too.

Comment: No, order-date and created-by are to diffrend columns.
Sorry i didn't understand your last post... My eng is... :/ So im looking columns

Comment: When you say "file" as well, do you literally mean a file (in a file share), or do you actually mean data in an `xml` column in a table?

Comment: Im mean data in an xml column in a table

Comment: We still **need** those expected results though, @ThomasTl .

Comment: ok, i edited my main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
(N'<orders xmlns="www address">
    <order order-no="000001">
        <order-date>2019-09-05</order-date>
        <created-by>storefront</created-by>
        <original-order-no>000001</original-order-no>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <taxation>gross</taxation>
        <invoice-no>0099999</invoice-no>
        <customer>
            <customer-name>Jonh Smith</customer-name>
            <customer-email>JonhSmith@gmail.com</customer-email>
        </customer>
    </order>
</orders>');

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'www address')
SELECT o.value(N'@order-no',N'varchar(10)') AS OrderNo
      ,o.value(N'(order-date/text())[1]',N'date') AS OrderDate
      ,o.value(N'(created-by/text())[1]',N'varchar(100)') AS CreatedBy
      ,o.value(N'(original-order-no/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS OriginalOrderNo
      ,o.value(N'(currency/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS Currency
      ,o.value(N'(taxation/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS Taxation
      ,o.value(N'(invoice-no/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS InvoiceNo
      ,o.value(N'(customer/customer-name/text())[1]',N'varchar(100)') AS CustomerName
      ,o.value(N'(customer/customer-email/text())[1]',N'varchar(100)') AS CustomerEMail
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes(N'/orders/order') A(o);
```

Be aware of the need to declare your (default) name space correctly. I used `.nodes()` because "orders" sounds like plural. Your sample includes just one order, but there might be more...

### UPDATE: Your additional "notes"

In any case of `1:n` relationship (many nodes related to one partent node), you need `.nodes()` in order to get each fragment as a separate row:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'www address')
SELECT o.value(N'@order-no',N'varchar(10)') AS OrderNo
      ,o.value(N'(order-date/text())[1]',N'date') AS OrderDate
      ,o.value(N'(created-by/text())[1]',N'varchar(100)') AS CreatedBy
      ,o.value(N'(original-order-no/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS OriginalOrderNo
      ,o.value(N'(currency/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS Currency
      ,o.value(N'(taxation/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS Taxation
      ,o.value(N'(invoice-no/text())[1]',N'varchar(10)') AS InvoiceNo
      ,o.value(N'(customer/customer-name/text())[1]',N'varchar(100)') AS CustomerName
      ,o.value(N'(customer/customer-email/text())[1]',N'varchar(100)') AS CustomerEMail
      ,n.value(N'(created-by/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(100)') AS Note_CreatedBy
      ,n.value(N'(creation-date/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS Note_CreatedBy
      ,n.value(N'(subject/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(100)') AS Note_CreatedBy
      ,n.value(N'(text/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(1000)') AS Note_CreatedBy
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes(N'/orders/order') A(o)
OUTER APPLY A.o.nodes(N'notes/note') B(n);
```

The last line will pick the current order and pass it into `.nodes()`. This will return  a derived set with one row per `<note>`.

Comment: it's working but i added some xml data to my main post ' <notes>
and now i get only first data from notes->note. but i would like to get all data from column.

Comment: get each of them

Comment: @ThomasTl See my update. And please for the next time: Instead of changing the original question rather start a new question. This will help future researchers to find close answers to close questions and it will avoid so-called *chameleon questions*...

Comment: Wow, you're the best ;)
And big sorry for edit my main post many times :( you have right - in my first post should be all on the beginning.

Comment: @ThomasTl It's okay, the SO-police is sometimes a bit to harsh to new-comers :-) It's okay to edit the OP in order to add details or clearify things, but you should not change the question itself (in this case: The structure of the question)... Happy Coding! (Ha! I just checked you aren't a new-comer at all :-) )

Comment: i checked my xml file and i have one more problem ? Could you help me one more time ? ;)

Comment: @ThomasTl, please start a new question for this and place a link here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OPENROWSET

```
CREATE DATABASE MyXmlDataBase
GO

USE MyXmlDataBase
GO

CREATE TABLE MyXmlTable
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Name NVARCHAR(50),
XMLData XML
)

INSERT INTO MyXmlTable(Name, XMLData)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\MyXmlFileOnDisk.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM MyXmlTable
```

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

Comment: Unfortunately, by "file" the OP did not actually mean a file... *"Im mean data in an xml column in a table"*